# Law and Brownian Bridge

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $Z_{t}= W_{t}-tW_{1}$ and $Y_{1}=\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}Z_{t}$, $(W_t, t \geq 0)$ standard Brownian motion

Find the law of $Y_{1}$

I know that $\textbf{P}(\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}W_{t}\geq x , W_{1}\leq y) = \textbf{P}(W_{1}\geq 2x-y)$  $\forall x\geq y$,$\forall x\geq 0$

Now I want to find $\textbf{P}(Y_{1}\geq x)$

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: This looks to me like an application of Girsanov especially if you can make sense of something like $$\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}W_{t} - tW_1\geq x , W_{1} = y \right) dy = \mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}W_{t} - t y \geq x , W_{1} = y \right) dy $$

Comment: Of course, using the *other* definition of BB makes the computation relatively direct.

Comment: other definiton of Brownian Bridge?

Comment: I think he means conditioning on the event that the Brownian motion is zero at one. I think you have define this conditioning as a limit.